# Execution of PHP code regarding database access using MongoDB is not giving desired results

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using WAMP server 64bit as well as MongoDB 64 bit in my Windows 7 machine. I have successfully configured MongoDB on WAMP server where `php_info()` page shows MongoDB Support Version 1.3.2RC1 enabled. But the problem is whenever I establish connection with MongoDB in PHP code the code runs but it does not reflect the changes in MongoDB console. Why is this so?

```
 <?php
 $connection = new MongoClient();
 //$db = $connection->sample;

 // select a collection:
 //$collection = $db->first;
 $collection = $connection->sample->test1;

 $doc = array(
 "name" => "MDB",
 "type" => "database",
 "count" => 2,
 "info" => (object)array( "x" => 203, "y" => 102),
 "versions" => array("0.9.7", "0.9.8", "0.9.9")
 );

 $collection->insert( $doc );

 echo "Inserted successfully....";

 $document = $collection->findOne();
 var_dump( $document );

 ?>
```

The above code retrieves the inserted document as it is on browser. But in mongo.exe console there is no data inserted. My default database is 'db'.

Comment: It looks like your example code is inserting into the `sample` database, not `db` as you suggest.  I would run `show dbs` in the `mongo` shell to see what databases have been created. I would also recommend you upgrade from the 1.3.2RC1 PHP driver (an old release candidate) to the latest driver released (currently 1.4.5).

Comment: after changing the database to 'db' and updating the driver still m facing the same problem..

Comment: are you sure you database is db and your not just reading the db.colleciton.find() notation as db being your database?

Comment: yaaa.....you are right.I am reading db.collection.find() notation as db.Am I going wrong?What is the difference in both of these databases?

Answer (score 0):

> My default database is 'db'

I think you may be confusing the `db` shell variable and the current database, which defaults to "test" unless you specify it a database name argument to the `mongo` command. Consider the following:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.5.5
connecting to: test
> db
test
> ^C
bye

$ mongo foo
MongoDB shell version: 2.5.5
connecting to: foo
> db
foo
>
```

The client tells me that it has connected to the "test" database by default, and evaluating the `db` variable reports its name as a string. If I connect again and specify "foo" as the command line argument, I see "foo" as the default database. Additionally, I can run `use <name>` when I'm in the shell to switch between databases.

In the PHP script above, you're accessing the "sample" database and "test1" collection when you evaluate `$connection->sample->test1`.